# Evaluate the directional derivative along the curve of intersection of the two spheres..

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

I am given $f(x.y.z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$ at $(3.4.5)$ along the curve of intersection of the two

surfaces $2x^2+2y^2-z^2=25$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$

And evaluate the directional derivative.

I know how to find out gradient of $f$ at $(3.4.5)$, but how can I find out unit vector that passes the curve of intersection of the two surfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the curve lies inside the intersection of the two surfaces given by

$$g(x, y, z) = 2x^2 + 2y^2 - z^2 - 25 = 0$$

and

$$ h(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0, $$

then that curve will have tangent vector normal both to $\nabla g$ and $\nabla h$ at $(3, 4, 5)$. So you can use cross product for example to find that.

If you do not want to use cross product, then we try to parametrize by

$$2x^2 + 2y^2 - (x^2 + y^2)  =25 \Rightarrow x^2 + y^2 = 25\Rightarrow z = \pm 5$$

So the curve can be parametrized by $\theta \mapsto (5\cos\theta, 5\sin\theta, 5)$ and the point $(3, 4, 5)$ corresponds to $\theta = \arccos (3/5)$.

Comment: Is there any other ways besides cross product to evaluate the unit vector?

Comment: Um.... by solving linear equations given by dot products? But cross product is the fastest way I guess.  @nany

Comment: Yep, but we haven't talked about cross product yet in class, so not sure whether I can use it.

Comment: Could you parametize (not sure its a right word) the two equations like r(t) and find out the vector..?

Comment: @nany: Please see the edit.

Comment: Ok thank you but how can I evaluate unit direction vector using parametization..? sorry for so many questions;

Comment: By taking derivative, you got the tangent vector. Then divide by its length to get an unit vector. @nany

Comment: Ok then what should be the value of t..?? cause it is vector valued function,

Comment: @nany: $\theta$ is just $t$. It is just the name of the variable.